# .vimrc settings are not loaded under "screen"?

Tags: vim, ssh, gnu-screen

When I ssh to one of my servers and do "ls", the folders are highlighted blue. If I open a file typing "vi filename" all my .vimrc settings are loaded.

As soon, however, as I run "screen", all the folders are green, when I open to edit a file using vi, none of my .vimrc settting work unless I use "vim filename".

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you determining that your `~/.vimrc` is not being loaded when you use `screen`? What are the values of `HOME` and `TERM` environment variables before starting `screen` and after starting `screen`?

Comment: I might be wrong but then what is the problem then? The values are bash-3.2$ echo $TERM
screen
bash-3.2$ echo $HOME
/home/codecrack

Comment: Sorry, I wanted _both_ `TERM` and `HOME` values before _and_ after running `screen`. My theory is `screen` is scrambling one or both of them...

Comment: Check the output of `which vi` both before and after starting `screen`. It sounds like your `PATH` is different, and in one care `vi` is a link to `vim`, but in the other it's just plain old-fashioned `vi`.

Comment: Maybe your settings for login vs. non-login shells are different. Try running screen with `screen -l` to start in login mode.

Comment: Screen _does_ garble the TERM environment variable. It is frequently just set to screen IIRC

Comment: sehe: how do I ungarble the TERM environment when running screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vim, you can type `:scriptnames` to view all loaded scripts.
The `vimrc` will show at the top if loaded.

---

Type `:version` to view how vim locate the `.vimrc` file, for example:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

`vim` will load user vimrc file: `$HOME/.vimrc`.
`HOME` is your bash env var, type `echo $HOME` in the terminal to view the value.

---

You can type `:echo $MYVIMRC` to view which vimrc was used at last.

---

Ultimately, you can type this command to start vim:

```
vim -V file.txt
```

It will print a lot of debug message. You can check what vim did, including sourcing vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are running `sudo vim` then `.vimrc` will never be applied from your home directory. Then you need to use the `:version` command (as **@kev** pointed out) to see where the system `vimrc` file is and put your settings there.